# How to add ignition msgs to ROS?

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to use gazebo plugins that use ignition messages in ROS project. I have installed libignition-msgs* libraries, but when I list all the types of messages in ROS with this command `$ rosmsg list` There is no ignition type of message.

How can I load the ignition-msgs into ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20543/how-to-add-ignition-msgs-to-ros?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2018-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ROS uses its own message description; Ignition Messages is a separate format.

All ROS tools will only handle ROS messages, you'll need Ignition tools to use Ignition messages.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2018-10-03**:
There is a Gazebo plugin ContainPlugin that publishes those ignition messages to the topic /contain. Does that mean my ROS node won't be able to subscribe to those topics?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-03**:
Correct. You can use an Ignition node to subscribe to the message and then convert it to ROS if necessary.